# want to fetch data from 4 joined tables?

Tags: mysql, laravel

the problem is  i have 3 posts in **posts** table same posts liked by other users in **user favourites** table but 3rd post is posted by user which is not liked by any other user but i want to show that post also

```
 $user_id = $request->input('user_id');
            $data = DB::table('posts')
            ->select('posts.*','posts__images.*','users.*','users__favourites.favourites')
            ->leftjoin('posts__images','posts__images.posts_id','=','posts.posts_id')
            ->join('users__favourites','users__favourites.posts_id','=','posts.posts_id')
            ->leftjoin('users','users.user_id','=','posts.user_id')
            ->where("users__favourites.user_id",'=',$user_id)
     
            ->get();
```

Comment: Please share models

Comment: Try `left join` on `users__favourites` instead of `join`